# C#: Reference Application Resource File

Tags: c#, file, path, application-resource

If I have a File `Default.html` in my project

[image]

How can I read it in code? I need the path

## One Possible Solution

`./Controls/MarkdownEditor/Templates/Default.html` works too. Also I set "Copy to output directory" to "Copy if newer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally using this:

```
   Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(
            "MarkDownEditMVVM.Controls.MarkDownWditor.Templates.Default.Html");
```

Unless you are using special namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the build action for that file to "Embedded Resource" in Visual Studio (right click the file and choose properties).

Then read the file in your code like this:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();  
Stream stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(asm.GetName().Name + ".Default.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [AppDomain.BaseDirectory Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx)  or [AppDomainSetup.ApplicationBase Property (System)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.applicationbase.aspx)

and [Path.Combine Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) to get to the directory required?